# MySQL visit = visit +1 , staring behavior

Tags: php, mysql

I haw active site for one day. Inside pages i haw this function

```
public function visit_update($link){
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET visit = visit + 1 WHERE link = \"$link\" ");
}
```

Every user has a unique link. I haw one active user only, because of testing (page is currently in testing).

Last night for one active user it was counted 50 visits in database. Today i when i was checking it, it was 560 visits. I haw also a google analytic activated and there it was counting for that page 50 or so visits and 3 visitors , because I was testing in 3 different explorers.

The function dos not repeat it self , and only counting visitors that are not owners of the page. How is that possible ?

**Update:**

I went throe raw logs , and fount out two IP addresses (66.249.66.87 and 66.249.72.210) that was visiting my site all night and they are from google. How do I distinguish real web browsers from dummy like robots in PHP ? is that possible ?

Comment: Impossible to say without the code in context where you call this method.  But, it is possible to say that you are calling ti 560 times, either because of faulty loop or branch logic, or because of faulty rewrite rules, or something else.

Comment: Also, don't rely on Google Analytics to find out how many times a script is called. GA does lots of things to limit the number of times it registers if via redirects and stuff like that.  Instead you must view your web logs directly.

Comment: Is it possible that google robots are checking page but not showing in analytics ?  And how do i prevent them from updating visits?

Comment: You will have to detect bots by their user agent string

Comment: @munge83 Could be robots if it is a public page, you will have to find them in your web logs.

Comment: @Michael I haw mode rewrite but was testing page when I refresh page it updates the database with +1 and seams like working fine bud from last night to today different for 500 views . how is that possible?

Comment: I went throe raw logs , and fount out two IP addresses (66.249.66.87 and 66.249.72.210) that was visiting my site all night and they are from google. How do I distinguish real web browsers from dummy like robots in PHP ? is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect crawlers by looking at the User Agent of the visiting browser most web crawlers indicate that they are a crawler. An example of crawler detection code can be found [here](http://www.cult-f.net/detect-crawlers-with-php/).

Answer (score 0):

You should check user session before updating site visit count.

```
public function visit_update($link){
      if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])
      {
            $query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET visit = visit + 1 WHERE link = \"$link\" ");
      }
}
```

This will update the visit count only for active members on your site.

Comment: the page must be public and counting people that are not loged in owners of that particular page.

Answer (score 0):

you could prevent updating the value too often with:

```
UPDATE user
SET visit = visit+1, last_visit = CURDATE()
WHERE link = $link AND last_visit < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 MIN
```

Comment: then I don't haw real visitors count. I need something that will know when robots come to check the page and real browsers.